# I want to get the column name and the Id in function PLSQL

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I tried this code and it didn't work, how can I return specific column with the Id from the function?

```
create or replace function getData(column_name varchar2,emp_id number)
 return varchar2 is 
 name varchar2(100);
 sql_stmt VARCHAR2(100);
begin 
    sql_stmt :='SELECT ' || column_name
     || ' FROM employees'||
        'WHERE EMPLOYEE_ID ='||emp_id;
     execute immediate sql_stmt into name using emp_id;
     return name;
end;   
select getData('FIRST_NAME',EMPLOYEE_ID) 
from employees
WHERE EMPLOYEE_ID=100
```

Comment: what does "not work" mean?

Comment: just do `select getData('FIRST_NAME',EMPLOYEE_ID)  from dual `

Comment: it returned this error ORA-00933

Comment: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended
ORA-06512: at "TRAINEE.GETDATA", line 9

Comment: `FROM employees' || 'WHERE EMPLOYEE_ID` gets you `FROM employeesWHERE EMPLOYEE_ID`. Add a blank after employees or before WHERE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is with these lines

```
     || ' FROM employees'||
        'WHERE EMPLOYEE_ID ='||emp_id;
```

It generates the statement `SELECT FIRST_NAME FROM employeesWHERE EMPLOYEE_ID = 100` which fails because of the missing space. Let's fix that and it works.

However, you're doing

```
     execute immediate sql_stmt into name using emp_id;
```

The keyword `USING` implies that there are bind variables but the string sql_stmt is hardcoded (you're just concatenating everything) and doesn't have bind variables. To use bind variables use the following syntax:

```
create or replace function getData(column_name varchar2,emp_id number)
 return varchar2 is 
 l_name varchar2(100);
 l_sql_stmt VARCHAR2(100);
begin 
    l_sql_stmt :='SELECT ' || column_name
     || ' FROM employees'||
        ' WHERE EMPLOYEE_ID = :emp_id';
    execute immediate l_sql_stmt into l_name using emp_id;
    return l_name;
end;   
/

SELECT getData('FIRST_NAME',100) as my_data 
  FROM employees 
 WHERE EMPLOYEE_ID=100 ;

my_data
----------
Steven
```

Note, bind variables cannot be column names so that needs to be concatenated and I prefixed the variables with "l_" for readability.